# Transforming string to an array of characters to extract and check date and ignore time

Tags: c#, c, string, date

I have strings containing dates, like this one: "2020-03-10T12:53:02".

I have [a CSV file full of dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgT2Z.png). I want to select the date of 2020-03-10 only but I don't know-how while the time exists.

Comment: One option: split the string on `T` and remove/discard the second part so you are left with `2020-03-10`, just the date. Please show us your attempt at solving this so we can help you out.

Comment: 'C' and 'C#' are two different languages.  Please pick only one

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the string ignoring the time, and the format is always "yyyy-MM-dd", then simply do:

```
var date = "2020-03-10T12:53:02".Substring(0, 10);
```

If you need a `DateTime` ignoring the time info then:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-10T12:53:02").Date;
```

If incorrectly formatted dates are a possibility, then use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

Comment: so it should be like: var date = temp.Substring(0, 10); but I don't know if that works? and the Var type is not glowing so I don't think it's working

Comment: @joesouaid `var` is not a type, its simply implicitly typed variables. Change it to explict types: `string date = "2020-03-10T12:53:02".Substring(0, 10);` or `DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("2020-03-10T12:53:02").Date;`

Comment: ok the problem left is that the date is inserted as a string in an array called char temp[100] using a for loop, so how could I use temp in substring instead of " "?

Comment: @joesouaid You might want to ask a new question with more information of the problem you are facing and what you've tried so far. You keep piling information that is not in your opening question. When you ask, provide all relevant information so people can help you. An online help center through comments is not what this place is for.

Comment: @joesouaid you don't need to post the exact code, post a reduced example of what your stuck with.